# Laravel pivot relation without specify one of them

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a table to persist all reactions available on the app (reactions) and N tables to be related to this in many-to-many relation with a pivot table.

**Ex:**
[image: ERM]

```
// Post Model
public function reactions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Reaction::class, 'reactions_posts')
        ->with('reactors')->groupBy('reaction_id');
}

// Reactions Model
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'reactions_posts');
}

public function reactors(){
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'reactions_posts');
}
```

Once N models could be related to `Reactions` model using a pivot, I am looking for a better way to relate Post x Reaction, Event x Reaction and all required models who will be related using this same principle, since this way would create some dependency of Post, Event and all on Reaction model.

Comment: Have you considered using Polymorphic Relationships?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Comment: Yes, but seems that I need to add dependency on Reactions by related models as well, and I wan't some how remove this dependency.